# Why does cmdLine.run('clear') give me an error?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.10

I am trying to learn to use espeak and I am following a tutorial, but I am stuck on the very first step. When I try to run this python code:

```
import subprocess as cmdLine
cmdLine.run("clear")

speech = 'This is what we want espeak to say'

command = 'espeak -x -v ' + 'mb-us1 ' + chr(34) + speech + chr(34)
print (command)
print ("")
```

All I'm getting is:

```
PS C:\Users\lukas\New folder> & C:/Users/lukas/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe "c:/Users/lukas/New folder/hello.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\lukas\New folder\hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    cmdLine.run("clear")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
PS C:\Users\lukas\New folder>
```

I don't understand what's wrong. All I want is to get `cmdLine.run('clear')` to work.

Comment: That tutorial is apparently intended for Linux.  On Windows, the command is `cls` rather than `clear`.

Comment: Try: `print("\033[H\033[J", end="")`